# Why must a and p be relatively prime in Fermat's Little Theorem?

Tags: prime-numbers

A variant of Fermat's Little Theorem states that $a^{p - 1} \equiv 1~mod~p$ if $a$ is not divisible by $p$.

Why is this last condition important? Why must $a$ and $p$ be relatively prime?

Comment: If $a$ is divisible by $p$, then $a^{p-1}\equiv 0\pmod p$.

Comment: Beat me by 20 seconds @BrianM.Scott ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $p$ divides $a$, then $a\equiv 0\bmod p$, so you will have
$$a^{p-1}\equiv 0^{p-1}\equiv 0\not\equiv 1\bmod p.$$
If you prefer a statement of Fermat's little theorem that doesn't have this restriction:
$$a^p\equiv a\bmod p$$
for any integer $a$ (regardless of whether it's relatively prime to $p$).

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ is divisible by $p$, then $a^{p-1} \equiv 0$ (mod $p)$.